# How to modify the standard HelloARcontroller script to instantiate one time?

Tags: c#, arcore

i want to modify the standard c# code HelloARcontroller to instantiate one time. So by touching the screen it will come only 1 time.
Can someone help me with this please?

```
if (Frame.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
{
    var andyObject = Instantiate(AndyAndroidPrefab, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);

    // Create an anchor to allow ARCore to track the hitpoint as understanding of the physical
    // world evolves.
    var anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

    // Andy should look at the camera but still be flush with the plane.
    if ((hit.Flags & TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon) != TrackableHitFlags.None)
    {
        // Get the camera position and match the y-component with the hit position.
        Vector3 cameraPositionSameY = FirstPersonCamera.transform.position;
        cameraPositionSameY.y = hit.Pose.position.y;

        // Have Andy look toward the camera respecting his "up" perspective, which may be from ceiling.
        andyObject.transform.LookAt(cameraPositionSameY, andyObject.transform.up);
    }

    // Make Andy model a child of the anchor.
    andyObject.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the instantiated object. Make a global gameobject variable in your class

```
GameObject andyObject = null;
```

and then in your raycast check, check if it is already instantiated first

```
if (andyObject==null && Frame.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
{
    andyObject = Instantiate(AndyAndroidPrefab, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);

    // Create an anchor to allow ARCore to track the hitpoint as understanding of the physical
    // world evolves.
    var anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

    // Andy should look at the camera but still be flush with the plane.
    if ((hit.Flags & TrackableHitFlags.PlaneWithinPolygon) != TrackableHitFlags.None)
    {
        // Get the camera position and match the y-component with the hit position.
        Vector3 cameraPositionSameY = FirstPersonCamera.transform.position;
        cameraPositionSameY.y = hit.Pose.position.y;

        // Have Andy look toward the camera respecting his "up" perspective, which may be from ceiling.
        andyObject.transform.LookAt(cameraPositionSameY, andyObject.transform.up);
    }

    // Make Andy model a child of the anchor.
    andyObject.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
}
```